# How to convert this json into string and get value of the 'id' property

Tags: c#, json, moodle-api

I want to return only  course id within jsonList.but My code is not working.

My json output:

```
"{\"courses\":[{\"id\":5,\"fullname\":\"Course temp\",\"displayname\":\"Course temp\",\"shortname\":\"ct\",\"categoryid\":17,\"categoryname\":\"Course templates\",\"sortorder\":40002,\"summary\":\"\",\"summaryformat\":1,\"summaryfiles\":[],\"overviewfiles\":[],\"contacts\":[],\"enrollmentmethods\":[\"manual\"],\"idnumber\":\"\",\"format\":\"topics\",\"showgrades\":1,\"newsitems\":5,\"startdate\":20120160,\"enddate\":20120160,\"maxbytes\":0,\"showreports\":0,\"visible\":1,\"groupmode\":0,\"groupmodeforce\":0,\"defaultgroupingid\":0,\"enablecompletion\":1,\"completionnotify\":0,\"lang\":\"\",\"theme\":\"\",\"marker\":0,\"legacyfiles\":0,\"calendartype\":\"\",\"timecreated\":1583825606,\"timemodified\":1583910617,\"requested\":0,\"cacherev\":1583913808,\"filters\":[{\"filter\":\"displayh5p\",\"localstate\":0,\"inheritedstate\":1},{\"filter\":\"mathjaxloader\",\"localstate\":0,\"inheritedstate\":1},{\"filter\":\"activitynames\",\"localstate\":0,\"inheritedstate\":1},{\"filter\":\"mediaplugin\",\"localstate\":0,\"inheritedstate\":1}],\"courseformatoptions\":[{\"name\":\"hiddensections\",\"value\":0},{\"name\":\"coursedisplay\",\"value\":0}]}],\"warnings\":[]}"
```

My code:(I want to return only `id`)

```
public int GetCourseDetails(Course course)
{
    string URI = "http://localhost/Moodle/webservice/rest/server.php";
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.QueryString.Add("wstoken", "49345fa96c58118326b874bxxxxx");
        wc.QueryString.Add("wsfunction", "core_course_get_courses_by_field");
        wc.QueryString.Add("moodlewsrestformat", "json");
        wc.QueryString.Add("field", "shortname");
        wc.QueryString.Add("value",course.shortname);


        var response_data = wc.UploadValues(URI, "POST", wc.QueryString);

        var response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response_data);
       // return response;
        var k = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(response);

        foreach (var a in k)
        {
            id = (a["id"]);
        }
        return id;

    }
}
```

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924923/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-object-e-g-namevalue-into-type-s#comment107788267_60924923 .

Answer (score 0):

Since your root object is not array, you need to Deserialize Json to `dynamic` instead of `List<dynamic>`, then select first course via this dynamic object and get `id` as follow:

```
var k = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);

var courseList = k.courses;
id = Convert.ToInt32(courseList[0]["id"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add reference to `System.Web.Extensions`:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonObj =jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(response);
var id=int.Parse(jsonObj.courses[0]["id"]);
```